# Use web page framework (i.e. Bootstrap) only on application part, not (static) website pages?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already have a design for a website. If I would use i.e. Bootstrap, it would take a lot of work to convert bootstrap to the design (more than I would gain from the framework). Yet this only applies to the design and relatively static pages (home, content). 
I feel however that I would gain benefit if using Bootstrap for the application part (inputs with error messages, buttons, date picker, and so on). 
Would there be a problem just using some elements without the "frame"  around it (no BS-grid)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a great question. I tried to clarify the header a bit. Please explain a little more what you mean by "application" part. The UI mechanics alone, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

No there will be no problem but take cae that you also take the css and js while of the part you want want in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise bootstrap to include only what you need, just go to this page:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

When you finish to add the elements you need, scroll to the bottom of the page and click "compile and download". You will then have a zip file with all you need from Bootstrap.

It is a good idea to keep your **config.json** file always available, so you can return to the same page, upload your config file and start from there, in case you want to add minor changes to your customised Bootstrap.